# Search Module result

Tags: search

i want the search results linked to the related page.i want to link the related pages to view detail and before it there would be text

**In format**

1.Result1 ***View detail***

1.Result2 ***View detail***

How would i do that..what should i write on result code and also how would i limit the character limit to result text

Regards,
Neha

Comment: Please post the relevant portions of the templates you are working with, as your question is quite vague. If you haven't already, please review the documentation for the search results tag: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/search/results.html

Comment: <td width="30%" valign="top"><b><a href="{auto_path}">{title}</a></b></td>
How can i change the base path as i am not getting the correct base path of current site and i want to link to related pages..How would i get the correct URL

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking what I think you're asking then you would need to set the base path for each channel within the channel's preferences.